# Функции empty и isset возвращают некорректный результат

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу сайт для самообучения. На данном моменте остановился на скрипте входа на сайт пользователя с помощью полей `"Логин"` и `"Пароль"`. Все как положено - форма, скрипт обработки этой формы. В общем, при нажатии на кнопку `"Вход"` обрабатывается скрипт, который проверяет корректность данных (сравнивает их с базой данных, в которой находятся зарегистрированные пользователи). В этом скрипте, сначала берутся данные из массива `$_POST`.

```
$login = $_POST['login]';
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Далее, эти данные проверяются на значение функцией `isset`:

```
if(!isset($login) or !isset($password)) {
    exit("Пользователь с таким логином или паролем не найден");
}
```

И когда я нажимаю на кнопку `"Вход"`, то скрипт завершается выводом сообщения

> "Пользователь с таким логином или паролем не найден"

но самое интересное то, что я ставил перед этим условием вывод этих двух переменных (`$login` и `$password`), у меня они нормально вывелись и показали как раз то, что я вводил в полях "Логин" и "Пароль".

**В чем может быть проблема?**

Так же пробовал вместо `!isset` ставить `empty`, все равно завершается ошибкой не существования переменных `$login` и `$password`.

Я запаковал эти два файла в архив по [адресу](http://www.fayloobmennik.net/3045102).
Сюда почему то не получилось

Comment: Дайте оба файла в минимальном варианте (форма и обработчик, достаточные для получения ошибки), подумаем. Пока можно только предполагать (форма не туда уходит, переменные где-то в процессе затираются, опечатка в конце концов)

Comment: Я разобрался. Проблема была в Html Редиректе, который стоял в конце страницы.

Comment: @ЛехаЕмельяненко , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239453/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0/708189#708189

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Во-первых, не нужно писать "гирлянды" аля **isset($a) || isset($b) ... || isset($n)**? достаточно перечислить их через запятую **isset($a,$b,...$c)**.
2. Во-вторых, ошибка корее всего в том, что в форме не указан метод передачи данных - **method="POST"**.
3. Если всё-таки с п.2 всё нормально, то попробуйте сделать следующее:

   ```
   $login = !empty($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : null;
   $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
   if(!isset($login,$password)){
       exit('Error!');
   }
   ```

Comment: Выводит все равно error. Форма прописана
<form action="./functions/testreg.php" method="post">
Тут находятся поля 
<input name="login" type="text" size="16" maxlength="16">
<input name="password" type="password" size="16" maxlength="16">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
Все это прописано в файле index.php.

Comment: @Deonis вы не поверите, я тоже не знал про `isset($a,$b,...$c)` %) Спасибо)

Только он не `OR`, а `AND` (см пункт 1).

Comment: Зачем городить и `empty` и `isset`-когда хватит просто `empty`, 1 условие, за место 3х.

Answer (score -1):

Может быть проблема в области видимости переменных?