# Как сделать редирект после выполнения php скрипта?

Tags: redirect, php

Нужно для системы регистрации. Т.е. пользователь нажимает кнопку "Вход", выполняется скрипт, находящийся в отдельном файле, обрабатывающий данные которые ввел пользователь (логин, пароль) и потом нужно перенаправить пользователя обратно на главную страницу. Но когда я вставляю в конец скрипта редирект, то встречаюсь с проблемой описанной в моем предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239046/php-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-empty-%D0%B8-isset-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82)

Может для этого есть специальные решения?

Comment: Функция header подходит?

Comment: Вообще я думаю, что тут просто надо как то скрипт организовать. Возможно и header подойдет, просто я не знаю куда его вставить. Если вставляю в конец скрипта то встречаюсь с проблемой описаной в теме по ссылке.

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку - вы используете куки или сессии? Думаю, что нет. Поэтому, при возврате на страницу авторизации, абсолютно естественно, что вы будете видеть форму для залогинивания.

Comment: Если  форма входа находится на главной (например где-то справа вверху). Обработка входа это отдельный скрипт. Объясните почему у вас ПОСЛЕ редиректа на главную ЕЩЕ раз происходит (?) вызов обработчика входа (логина) пользователя??? Может нужно `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'...` - вопрос не вполне понятен.

Answer (score 1):

Редирект осуществляется отправкой НТТР заголовка `Location:` с помощью функции `header()`. После отправки этого заголовка в обязательном порядке должен вызываться оператор `exit`, поскольку сама по себе отправка этого заголовка не прекращает выполнение скрипта. То есть в общем случае это код

```
header("Location: /index.php");
exit;
```

В данном конкретном случае, если была нажата кнопка ВХОД, то метод будет `POST` - при условии что у вас в форме он указан - а если сработал редирект, то `GET`.

```
//В скрипте обработки входа (логина)
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $login = $_POST['login]';
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // тут дальнейшая обработка - проверка, запись в сессию
    
    header("Location: /index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Чуток испугался :) Как это так "автора давно нет"? Но уже понял. Думаю что отредактированный ответ пригодиться всем кого посылает :) гугл.

Answer (score -1):

Если ты используешь AJAX-запрос, то в случае success я выполнял следующее:

```
// вместо $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"] укажи путь к странице, на которую должен происходить редирект

window.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]?>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Ссылаясь на твой предыдущий вопрос и на этот тоже:

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])) {
   $login = $_POST['login'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   if ($row['password'] != $password) { //Не верный логин или пароль }
   else {  
          // Тут я задавал значения сессии и еще

        $_SESSION['USER_LOG_IN'] = 1; 

           /* 1 означает что пользователь авторизовался,
              а если сделать `Выход`, то значение при запросе на выход надо изменить на 0.*/


        exit(header("Location: /index.php"));
   }
}
```

Я использовал отдельную страницу для входа. Вписал в `index.php` код:

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])) include ('login.php');
else include('ipage.php');
```

и при этом в `index` файле у меня было мало кода, и определенный код записывался в определенных файлах, что при запросе `GET` вставлялся в `index.php`

Поэтому на той же странице может наблюдаться циклический редирект.Это я не проверял